# How to log Δ character using LOG4CXX library

Tags: log4cxx

My project is multi-byte and the data to be logged contains the `Δ` character

When i log　I use it like this,

```
Logger::getLogger(log_name)->info(szBuf);

void info(const std::wstring& msg) const;
```

but the `Δ` character is displayed `?`

How can I output it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this has to do with how log4cxx decodes characters in the locale that you are currently in.  The `?` is a replacement character, indicating that the given character cannot be decoded in your current locale.

You can fix it by doing the following when your application starts up:

```
std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "" ); /* Set locale for C functions */
std::locale::global(std::locale("")); /* set locale for C++ functions */
```

Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/faq.html#unicode_supported